# how to Change the default string encoding to UTF 8?

Tags: .net, string, encoding

I guess .net uses UTF 16 for string encoding.

1. How to change it to use UTF 8?
2. What are the side effects of changing the encoding?
3. My .net (c#) app totally holds on to around 120 mb for string instances. And I assume if I can change the default encoding to `UTF 8` the footprint would reduce to half.

Answer (score 10):

No need to guess. It does indeed use UTF-16 internally (see the remarks section of the [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) Structure page on MSDN).

You can't change how .NET handles strings internally.

If you need to change the encoding for output, use the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class, in particular, for UTF-8 you can simply use the static property [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx).

I understand wanting to save the space, but perhaps you need to rethink the application design and have these strings externally (i.e. loaded from the filesystem or a database) and not compiled into the application?